# klogd killed with SIGABRT. fdsan: attempted to close file descriptor 3, expected to be unowned

Tags: logging, kernel, android-12

**Problem Description**

klogd worked fine on Android 9 or 10, but no longer works on Android 12. I am working on project with klogd version 1.5.0. This version of klogd has some file descriptor related issues. [fdsan documentation](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/master/docs/fdsan.md#Enabling-fdsan-as-a-C_library-implementer) refers that from API 30 fdsan has set default value to ANDROID_FDSAN_ERROR_LEVEL_FATAL
Due to which klogd is getting killed immediately after some descriptor issue of klogd.

**Error message:**

**logcat logs**

```
libc    : fdsan: attempted to close file descriptor 3, expected to be unowned, actually owned by FILE* 0x70fde09018
libc    : Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 6539 (klogd), pid 6539 (klogd)
crash_dump64: obtaining output fd from tombstoned, type: kDebuggerdTombstoneProto
tombstoned: received crash request for pid 6539
crash_dump64: performing dump of process 6539 (target tid = 6539)
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE), fault addr --------
Abort message: 'fdsan: attempted to close file descriptor 3, expected to be unowned, actually owned by FILE* 0x70fde09018'
    x0  0000000000000000  x1  000000000000198b  x2  0000000000000006  x3  0000007fe1acfa30
    x4  0080808080808080  x5  0080808080808080  x6  0080808080808080  x7  8080808080808080
    x8  00000000000000f0  x9  5b25f7251ae4d21f  x10 0000000000000001  x11 0000000000000000
    x12 0101010101010101  x13 00000003f6f09532  x14 0016da37cf86e56c  x15 0000000000000010
    x16 00000070fe36ed20  x17 00000070fe348d80  x18 00000071028d4000  x19 000000000000198b
    x20 000000000000198b  x21 0000007101ddf010  x22 0000000000000003  x23 0000007fe1acf828
    x24 0000007fe1acfb20  x25 0000007fe1acf7a0  x26 0000007fe1acf760  x27 ffffff80ffffffc8
    x28 000000579164fc4e  x29 0000007fe1acfac0
    lr  00000070fe2fe6d0  sp  0000007fe1acf6e0  pc  00000070fe2fe6f4  pst 0000000000000000
backtrace:
      #00 pc 000000000008d6f4  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (fdsan_error(char const*, ...)+564) 
      #01 pc 000000000008d3f8  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (android_fdsan_close_with_tag+752) 
      #02 pc 000000000008db78  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (close+16) 
      #03 pc 00000000000037e0  /vendor/bin/klogd (write_pid+176) 
      #04 pc 0000000000003eb4  /vendor/bin/klogd (main+628) 
      #05 pc 0000000000082180  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__libc_init+96)
```

How to resolve this issue without changing fdsan default level and without reverting API level?

*Fixes tried*
klogd works after setting fdsan default_level in libc/bionic/fdsan.cpp to ANDROID_FDSAN_ERROR_LEVEL_WARN_ONCE. But this might reduce chances of catching file descriptor bugs. This is not feasible approach.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by upgrading the old version in build.gradle try to understand it and upgrade the old versions,
I tried upgrading the library " implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:x.y.z' " and it worked.